# Naturally dissolving kidney stone through daily activities, food and drinking habits

Tags: diet, kidney-stones

To give you a brief introduction, while writing this post I was in a hospital bed and treated for getting rid of ~20mm of a kidney stone on my left side. The doctors followed the PCNL procedure.

Now, doctors informed me about another 5mm of stone on right kidney.

A quick look around the internet to find a solution to getting the stone out of my system with a natural process, many suggest:

- Drink loads of water
- Drink beer
- Take Apple cider vinegar
- Olive oil and lemon juice therapy
- Or, have another operation

Do natural remedies help for kidney stones?

Answer (score 3):

The one thing I would add to your natural remedy is cranberry juice and/or dried cranberries. Countless studies have shown a correlation between cranberry consumption and renal health.

I know for a fact cranberry consumption can help prevent kidney stones. I'm not sure about dissolving them, but it certainly won't hurt to add to your remedy list.

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14616463

Answer (score 0):

Once a stone is formed, to my knowledge, it will have to pass...I don't think that anything is available that will promote dissolving, if that is even possible.  Certainly large fluid intake combined with medication that relaxes the ureters (like Tamulosin) has been found to be effective...also important is prevention, with various regimens depending on the actual composition of the stone, based on treating the underlying precipitators for stone formation...5mm is borderline but with Tamulosin + heavy floods intake, might just pass...